Vercel flask deployment error: Unable to find any supported Python versions
I want to deploy flask app on Vercel
but whenever I try to deploy it, I get this error:
Error: Unable to find any supported Python versions.01:53:10.844Learn More: http://vercel.link/python-version

This is vercel.json file:


{
    "version":2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src":"./index.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python",
            "config":{"runtime":"python3.9"}
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src":"/(.*)",
            "dest":"/"
        }
    ]
}

I've tried changing Python versions to 3.6, 3.8 , 3.8, 3.11
Then someone told me to make a pipfile tried that but it's still not working
This is the Pipfile
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
flask = "*"
requests = "*"
python-dotenv = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"


chagne your vercel.json to this :
{
    "version":2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src":"./index.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python",
            "config":{"runtime":"python3.9"}
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src":"/",
            "dest":"/"
        }
    ]
}

changed src to "src":"/"
This worked for me.

Changing node js version from 20.x to 18.x in vercel project settings fixed the issue
It can be done via going to your Vercel dashboard and selecting the settings tab look for the node.js tab and select 18.x
refrence_image
